# x-tile on Ubuntu MATE 17.10 : seg fault (error 4 in libX11.so.6.3.0 && error 5...)

Tags: 17.10, window-manager, mate, tiling

I just installed `x-tile` through the repository `ppa:giuspen/ppa`. No errors on install but the application doesn't run. Throws a segmentation fault given in Title.

From `syslog`:

```
Jan 25 19:38:49 samsung kernel: [ 1071.162869] x-tile[6039]: segfault at 6c664eb0 ip 00007f7e64245c30 sp 00007ffcb5b95c78 error 4 in libX11.so.6.3.0[7f7e6421a000+134000]
Jan 25 19:39:05 samsung kernel: [ 1087.168214] x-tile[6071]: segfault at fffffffff560d490 ip 00007f04271b6c30 sp 00007ffc52008878 error 5 in libX11.so.6.3.0[7f042718b000+134000]
Jan 25 19:40:40 samsung kernel: [ 1182.583397] x-tile[6289]: segfault at ffffffff9c8e1640 ip 00007f25cae0ec30 sp 00007ffd3f946fe8 error 5 in libX11.so.6.3.0[7f25cade3000+134000]
Jan 25 19:40:47 samsung kernel: [ 1189.603948] x-tile[6304]: segfault at ffffffffb0ea3180 ip 00007f7c0592ac30 sp 00007ffc0458c5e8 error 5 in libX11.so.6.3.0[7f7c058ff000+134000]
```

Comment: Please report the bug to the PPA maintainer. Bug reports are off topic here.

Comment: Thank you. I have reported this to giuspen feedback, referencing this conversation. N0rbert has posted to LaunchPad. 
I understand now that this is a bug, but at the time of posting I did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I can understand, [giuspen's PPA does not have `x-tile` package for 17.10](https://launchpad.net/~giuspen/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=artful).
After adding it to my system I have the following:

```
$ apt-cache policy x-tile 
x-tile:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.5-3
  Version table:
     2.5-3 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe i386 Packages
```

So we get `x-tile` package from [universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=x-tile).

Just installed it with `sudo apt-get install x-tile`.

On launch from terminal it crashes and writes similar error message to `/var/log/syslog`:

> Jan 26 23:31:58 artful-mate kernel: [ 544.374814] x-tile[3880]: segfault at fffffffff96324e0 ip 00007f86797a3c30 sp 00007ffd67a56c58 error 5 in libX11.so.6.3.0[7f8679778000+134000]

By the way `libX11.so.6.3.0` library is installed with package `libx11-6:amd64`.

So I can confirm  this problem, I reported it to LaunchPad as [bug 1745676](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/x-tile/+bug/1745676).

On 16.04 LTS `x-tile` works normally.

**Update:** thanks to Giuspen for adding [corrected version to PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999919/x-tile-on-ubuntu-mate-17-10-seg-fault-error-4-in-libx11-so-6-3-0-error-5/1000173#comment1617447_1000173). Problem is fixed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:giuspen/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x-tile
```

Comment: Correct. I just added x-tile for 17.10 to the PPA

Comment: Yes. Installed from the ppa and can confirm that it is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working using the latest deb file from giuspen.

I downloaded the deb file for x-tile

```
wget http://www.giuspen.com/software/x-tile_2.5.1-1_all.deb
```

I removed the broken install and installed the deb file:

```
apt remove x-tile
gdebi x-tile_2.5.1-1_all.deb
```

This succeeded and now I have x-tile in MATE 17.10.

Comment: Made small edits. Seems to be really working solution. Thank you!